# Show comments in a popup

Tags: comments

I want to show comments in a popup for the page with `id=22`.

This is the anchor on whose click  the popup will open:

```
<a class="button button-small button-line-light comment-popup" 
    href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/comments-detail.php">View All</a>
```

If I have plain html in `comments-detail.php`, popup shows the html.

But when I try to get the comments list of page `id=22`, in `comments-detail.php`,  with the following simple code:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => 22
    );
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
?>
```

then I get the error:

> call to undefined function `get_comments()`

What am I doing wrong or is my approach totally wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're re-inventing the wheel here ;-)

### The Problem

You're bypassing WordPress with this approach, so that's explains the error message.

Accessing any custom file, within your theme directory, will **not** load WordPress core automatically.

### Already available

This is already supported by the WordPress core.

You should check out [`comments_popup_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link) and [`comments_popup_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comments_popup_script).

In general, you can get all your comments, for a given post with:

```
example.tld/?comments_popup=123
```

where `123` is some *post ID*.

You can override the default *comment popup template*, by placing your own version of the `comments-popup.php` file, in the current theme directory.

The default one is located in `/wp-includes/theme-compat/comments-popup.php`.

### Note on WP 4.2.2 - Incorrect inline documentation

In core we got [this description](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/43077a6ef8d58b7d6dfb7ab1e2560a0186e60c09/wp-includes/template.php#L450):

> - The template path is filterable via the 'comments_popup_template' hook.

but it's not correct. The template comes from:

```
$template = get_query_template( 'comments_popup', array( 'comments-popup.php' ) );
```

and within `get_query_template()` we have the following cleaning:

```
    $type = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9-]+|', '', $type );
```

where the type `comments_popup` is changed to `commentspopup`.

The correct filter is therefore:

```
add_filter( 'commentspopup_template', function( $template )
{   
    return $template;
} );
```

It looks like the correct type was meant to be `comments-popup` and not `comments_popup`. But then we can wonder why the underscore is removed - check out ticket [#21213](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21213) to read more on that.

I filed a core trac ticket here [#32989](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32989#), regarding the inline documentation.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping out.  I tried this                  <?php 
        comments_popup_script(400, 500); 
        comments_popup_link( 'No comments yet', '1 comment', '% comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments are off for this post');
        ?>                                                       It opens the popup with url http://localhost/example/?comments_popup=22                                                  But its blank .....

Comment: Did you override the `comments-popup.php` file or any PHP errors? @amritanshu

Comment: thanks a lot . But all above you mentioned above is too much for me. Going over my head.. I am going to try it.  So i think showing comments in modal overlay is not possible?

Comment: i included this line in my comments-detail.php        <?php include("../../../wp-load.php"); ?>                          And now it works fine :) . Always use this code in ajax popups . Something wrong with this approach???

Comment: Then you're not using what's available in WordPress -  No need to include this for *ajax* or *comments-popup*. You should let WordPress work better for you ;-) Use the `wp_ajax_{$myaction}` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$myaction}` hooks instead when working with ajax. Try to copy the `/wp-includes/theme-compat/comments-popup.php` file into your current theme directory. [Here's a live example](http://wptavern.com/?comments_popup=16179) of the comments popup. @amritanshu

Comment: Thanks a lot @birgire. I am going to try that and will keep you posted of any success